# How can I download and install custom roms for the droid x?

Tags: custom-roms, motorola-droid-x

I have a droid x. I'm told that my phone will be much faster if it has a custom rom. After some googling I read that rubix is a good option. I'd appreciate any instructions on how to go about obtaining and installing this custom rom on my phone, or any pointers to this effect.

Comment: Just do note that a Droid X has a locked bootloader therefore you will never be able to change the kernel of the device so you don't get 100% out of custom roms like other devices without the locked bootloader.

Comment: What sort of features will I be missing out on because of this? Thanks.

Comment: the primary thing the kernel controls is the clockspeed.  You won't be able to replace the stock kernel with any other kernel so you are stuck with whatever speeds the stock kernel allows you to overclock/underclock to

Comment: As I have come to understand it, things are getting more interesting for the locked bootloader with the advent of 2nd init.

Answer (score 1):

I think the instructions you find in [this thread](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/drod2169-x/93478-rubix-focused-1-6-a.html) are fairly clear, aside from the process of [rooting your phone](http://www.droid-life.com/2010/09/22/how-to-root-droid-x-running-official-android-2-2/) and installing [ROM Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&feature=search_result).

All the standard disclaimers apply, of course.  What you do with your phone is your business and nothing any of us say makes us responsible if you brick your device.